# Python async websocket client with async timer

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I need to have a long running websocket client that receives push messages from a websocket server and I need to monitor the client's connection state: if the connection goes down, I need to find out.

My approach is to periodically log a constant string, and trigger an alarm if ever the log message is not detected.

My idea: 1) have a websocket client that responds to irregularly incoming messages. And 2) at the same time have loop that stops logging a message when the websocket client throws a ConnectionClosed exeption.

I am intrigued by the new 3.5 async syntax. [This websocket](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets) implementation is specifically based on the asyncio. The [client](https://websockets.readthedocs.org/en/stable/intro.html#basic-example) in the docs look exactly like what I need.

However, I have no idea how to add a second coroutine that does my logging statements **and** somehow stops when the websocket connection throws the ConnectionClosed.

Here is something to start the conversation but that doesn't work because the alive method blocks the event loop. What I am looking for is an elegant solution to run both methods concurrently.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import asyncio
import logging

import websockets

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

is_alive = True


async def alive():
    while is_alive:
        logger.info('alive')
        await asyncio.sleep(300)


async def async_processing():
    async with websockets.connect('ws://localhost:8765') as websocket:
        while True:
            try:
                message = await websocket.recv()
                print(message)

            except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
                print('ConnectionClosed')
                is_alive = False
                break


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(alive())
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(async_processing())
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually the `run_until_complete` is blocking here, since it waits until `alive` finish.

You can solve it with 2 steps:

1. schedule coroutines with [`asyncio.ensure_future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.ensure_future) (immediately runs without waiting for results), each returning task.
2. wait for tasks to get finished with [`asyncio.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.wait)

The code like:

```
tasks = [
   asyncio.ensure_future(alive()),
   asyncio.ensure_future(async_processing())
]
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
```

As @Vincent mentioned `wait` accepts tasks, so `ensure_future` is needless:

```
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(asyncio.wait([   
   alive(),
   async_processing()
]))
```

Comment: You can pass a list of coroutines to `asyncio.wait`, no need to use `asyncio.ensure_future` in your example.

Comment: How i can add here additional code to reconnect to websocket server after closing connection?