# Async function blocking main thread

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, websocket, python-asyncio

Hello I am wanting to create a client socket via python, and I found this example (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49918082/12354066). The only problem I am wondering about is, I have a whole other program I want to implement this with, and it seems `loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))` is blocking the whole thread and not allowing me to execute any more functions i.e print(1) after `loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))`. I want to be able to listen & send messages, but I also want to be able to execute other after I begin listening, maybe this is better suited for threads and not async (I don't know much async..)

```
import websockets
import asyncio

class WebSocketClient():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    async def connect(self):
        '''
            Connecting to webSocket server

            websockets.client.connect returns a WebSocketClientProtocol, which is used to send and receive messages
        '''
        self.connection = await websockets.client.connect('ws://127.0.0.1:8765')
        if self.connection.open:
            print('Connection stablished. Client correcly connected')
            # Send greeting
            await self.sendMessage('Hey server, this is webSocket client')
            return self.connection


    async def sendMessage(self, message):
        '''
            Sending message to webSocket server
        '''
        await self.connection.send(message)

    async def receiveMessage(self, connection):
        '''
            Receiving all server messages and handling them
        '''
        while True:
            try:
                message = await connection.recv()
                print('Received message from server: ' + str(message))
            except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
                print('Connection with server closed')
                break

    async def heartbeat(self, connection):
        '''
        Sending heartbeat to server every 5 seconds
        Ping - pong messages to verify connection is alive
        '''
        while True:
            try:
                await connection.send('ping')
                await asyncio.sleep(5)
            except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
                print('Connection with server closed')
                break
```

main:

```
import asyncio
from webSocketClient import WebSocketClient

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Creating client object
    client = WebSocketClient()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # Start connection and get client connection protocol
    connection = loop.run_until_complete(client.connect())
    # Start listener and heartbeat 
    tasks = [
        asyncio.ensure_future(client.heartbeat(connection)),
        asyncio.ensure_future(client.receiveMessage(connection)),
    ]

    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
    print(1) # never gets executed
```

Comment: As the `run_until_complete` name says, asyncio's event loop takes over the control "until complete". You can add additional task(s) to perform other functions while the client is running. The code must by async or the new task(s) should be run in an executor (a separate thread). As you probably noticed, asyncio is not trivial, learning from examples will not give you the whole picture.